# Why a program starts slow but later gains the full speed?

Tags: c++, performance

I noticed that sometimes a program runs very slow but later the performance is good. For example, I have some code which I run in a loop and the first iteration takes ages but other iterations of the **same** code runs pretty fast. It's hard to name the circumstances because I can't figure it out and it seems that even single literal can affect this behavior. I prepared a small code snippet:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int num{ 100000 };

    vector<vector<int>> octs;
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < num; ++i)
    {
        octs.emplace_back(vector<int>{ 42 });
    }

    vector<int> datas;
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < num; ++i)
    {
        datas.push_back(42);
    }

    for (int n{ 0 }; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        cout << "start" << '\n';
        //cout << 0 << "start" << '\n';

        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        for (int i{ 0 }; i < num; ++i)
        {
            vector<int> points{ 42 };
        }

        auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);

        cout << time.count() << '\n';
    }

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The first two vectors are essential. At least with Visual Studio. Thought they're not in use they affect the performance a lot. Moreover, tweaking them also give performance effect (like change the order of initialization, remove `push_back` and allocate the necessary size in constructor). But this code as it is gives me the following results:

- with gcc there're no problems at all
- with clang the first iteration takes two times longer than the others
- with vs2013 the first iteration is 100 (yes, one hundred) times slower.

Moreover, with vs2013 if I uncomment the line `cout << 0 << "start" << '\n';` the performance problem goes away and all iterations are equal!

What's going on?

Comment: Cache misses become fewer & fewer

Comment: That for loop you are timing can be completely optimized away by the compiler.  Are you sure it actually runs in gcc and clang?  Also what settings did you use?

Comment: I'm not reading anything in my example. And how there can be less cache misses on the same code and the same data?

Comment: Because the cache isn't filled until the first time a load is done (be it code or data). So the first time it misses. There's also the branch predictor which becomes better after a few iterations of the loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I thought about it but it seems it not optimized - the timings are not 0. I used default release configuration with vs and non-optimized release config for others.

Comment: Then you are comparing apples to oranges.  Release build in MSVS has optimizations turned on by default.  You need to also turn on optimizations in gcc and clang to get a real comparison.

Comment: @nikitablack, it's relevant to all code on (even not so) modern architectures.

Comment: Is the problem that the first loop is 100 times slower, or that the non-optimized compilers don't speed up on second and subsequent passes?  Asking anything about performance without optimization is pointless.

Comment: The question was why the first iteration is slow? But now I see it happens only with vs2013 thought with full optimization. The difference between compilers can be because I'm running on different machines.

Comment: Since you never specified your target platform, this is an exercise in guessing. And pretty useless as a reference.

Comment: @IInspectable All I wanted to hear is - "yes, this is well known standard feature because the first 135 instructions need to warm up" or "some code compiles in machine code on the fly" or whatever. Now I can see the behavior I described is not common and very compiler/platform specific i.e. it's not a standard. It's also very good to know. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

For your first two loops, probably the biggest performance consideration is going to be the allocation of memory, and the copying of the `vector` contents to the larger buffer.  In this case, the fact that the loops appear to be 'gaining speed' is not surprising.

This is due to the implementation details of the `vector` class.  Let's look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

> Internally, vectors use a dynamically allocated array to store their
>   elements. This array may need to be reallocated in order to grow in
>   size when new elements are inserted, which implies allocating a new
>   array and moving all elements to it. This is a relatively expensive
>   task in terms of processing time, and thus, vectors do not reallocate
>   each time an element is added to the container.
>
> Instead, vector containers may allocate some extra storage to
>   accommodate for possible growth, and thus the container may have an
>   actual capacity greater than the storage strictly needed to contain
>   its elements (i.e., its size). **Libraries can implement different
>   strategies for growth to balance between memory usage and
>   reallocations, but in any case, reallocations should only happen at
>   logarithmically growing intervals of size so that the insertion of
>   individual elements at the end of the vector can be provided with
>   amortized constant time complexity (see push_back).**

So under the hood, the actual memory allocated for your `vector` might be much more than what you are actually using.  So the `vector` only needs to do the costly re-allocation and copy when you add a new element to the `vector` which wouldn't fit into its current buffer.  Moreover, since it says that re-allocations should only happen at logarithmically growing intervals, you can expect that the `vector` class is roughly doubling the buffer size every time it needs to re-allocate.  But note that the `vector` implementations on various platforms are highly tuned to be optimal for the most common usage patterns for the class, which could be one factor in the different performance you are seeing across tool chains and platforms.

So you should see the loops be slow on the first several executions, and then gain more speed as `push_back` and `emplace` operations need to do fewer re-allocations and copies to accommodate the new elements.

So I think this is the main fact you can use to reason about how long your first two loops should take to execute.  But for your specific examples, due to the simplicity of the program, the compiler may be taking some liberties with what code it generates.  So we could imagine that a sufficiently clever optimizing compiler might be able to see that your `vector`s will only be growing to a size which it knows at compile time, `num`.  And this is the biggest issue I suspect with your last loop, which seems like an arbitrary and useless test.  For example, the nested loop in loop 3 can be optimized away entirely.  I think this is the main reason why you are seeing such different run-time behavior across the different compilers.

If you want to get the real story, take a look at the assembly code that your compiler is generating.

Comment: This sounds good, but the two big vectors are not participating in time measurements. Also they are not mentioned in the measured code block. But still they affect somehow the behavior of the problem in vs2013. I agree that the best solution would be to look into the generated assembly but unfortunately I can't read the assembly.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought you were seeing and asking about the performance issues with each of the loops, and that the first two loops weren't just included because they have an effect on the third.

Comment: Nope, only the measured one. Sorry for the confusion. Btw, as far as I know gcc and clang uses coefficient of 2 for the calculation of new capacity but visual studio uses 50% capacity increase.